# Doesn't receive updated data from the database (Spring OneToMany relationship)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I'm new to java and now I'm writing a simple website for learning. I ran into this problem:

User entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Message> messages;
```

Message entity:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User author;
```

Controller:

```
Set<Message> messages = user.getMessages();
model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
```

And when I get the data for the first time (with **getMessages**), everything works fine. But after adding a Message, this function returns the same Set without a new Message. Although an entry in the database appears and if called:

```
messages = messageRepo.findAll();
```

the new Message appears in the list. After restarting the server, a new article appears in the method **getMessages**.
What is my fault, why is the data not updated after adding the new Message?

UPD:

Code for adding a Message:

```
@PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @Valid Message message,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model
    ) throws IOException {
        message.setAuthor(user);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);

            model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("message", null);
            messageRepo.save(message);
        }

        return "main";
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code how you add a message.

Comment: are you using cache

Comment: @AlexRudenko Added the code to the topic

Comment: @Hamza i think no

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the FETCHTYPE. Also add the code for how you are adding message and the relation between the two entities.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you add the author to the message but you didn't do the same thing for author:

For exemple add a new method in Author class for adding a new message:

```java
public class Author {
...
   public void addMessage(Message message){
        if(messages==null) messages= new HashSet();
        messages.add(message);
   }
...
}
```

and use it in your code like this:

```java
author.addMessage(message);
```

Note that you should define the hashCode method otherwise the HashSet will ignore the new messages.

Also If you don't have any constraint to use a bi-directional relation it would be better to use a uni-directional relation only (message -> author).